# Product of Schemes and Open Subsets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme and $U$ an open subset, view $U$ as a scheme also. Let $X\times X$ be the product in the category of schemes. Show that there exists an open subset $V$ of this product, such that $V = U\times U$ i.e. $V$ is a categorical product for the scheme $U$. Thus, we can view $U\times U$ as an open subset of $X\times X$.

Comment: We appreciate an effort on your part to solve the problem. I suggest you add your own attempt at solution with a reference describing where you got the problem from.

Comment: @Zach466920 If you have nothing worthy to say then do not respond to people's question. Especially when you do not understand the problem (which seems to be the case based on your other answers). The problem came from me in an attempt to solve something else, I am not even sure if it is true or not.

Comment: Well this isn't off to a good start. Anyway, I feel as if some part of you knows that this is true if you've gone through a construction of fiber products: if $p\colon X \times_S Y \to X$ is the first projection and $U\subseteq X$ is open then $U \times_S Y \simeq p^{-1}(U)$ in a natural way.

Comment: @Hoot The isomorphism here is an isomorphism of schemes over $S$? (Because if $X$ is a scheme over $S$, any open subset gets an induced scheme structure). Yes, that helps, I was able to fill in the gap I needed thanks to your help. Follow up question, what is the justification for this isomorphism? (By the way, I was trying to prove that the the image of a scheme under a diagonal map is locally closed. This is how it came up. )

Comment: As Hoot says, it is essentially part of the construction of fibred products. You should review that.

Comment: @ZhenLin "Review that", unfortunately I have never constructed a fiber product. I just assumed that products exist in the category of $S$-schemes. I was wondering though, if one can prove this result using only the universal property of the product, without going back to its construction?

Comment: It definitely follows from the universal property. In the argument that I and probably Zhen have in mind the universal property is exploited in order to construct the object — this, I think, is something new for most students. Really what we should do is draw some diagrams but I'm too lazy to TeX it right now. I think it's mostly spelled out at the start of Ch. 7 (I think?) in Vakil.

Comment: It does not follow from the universal property. You have to show that the product of open immersions is an open immersion; it follows from the fact that open immersions are closed under base change and composition, but that's still something that needs to be checked.